# Explain a python construction

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples in 'tups' and have applied the following code to filter. The list of tuples have the format `[(floata,stra1,stra2),(floatb,strb1,strb2),...etc]`

```
keys=sorted({t[2] for t in tups}) 
for key in keys:     
    group=filter(lambda t: t[2]==key,tups)     
    print '{}:\n\tmax: {}\n\tmin: {}'.format(key,max(group),min(group))
```

Initially I thought the curly brackets was a mistake and changed them to square brackets. I did not get a syntax error but the code did not work. As a last resort I changed the brackets back and everything was fine. Can someone explain the construction. Is this a dictionary comprehension? Where is this explained in the documentation?

Comment: Which curly brackets are you talking about here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the curly brackets in the first line, [this is a set comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp). This will create a set of the third item from every tuple in `tups`. A set is similar to a list, but without order, and therefore cannot contain duplicates.

If you mean the brackets in the string, this is just [new-style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings). Calling `str.format()` changes those braces into the passed values.

Comment: @Wooble Didn't see the other ones when I answered, I'd presume you are right.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This explains the construction. I was under the impression that the curly braces defined a dictionary, I was not thinking sets. The curly braces gave me an error in Python 2.5 but ran in 2.7 and I was wondering why.

Comment: @user1642486, it seems that set comprehensions were backported from 3.1 into 2.7, but I don't think they updated the 2.7 documentation to reflect it. See http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features

Answer (score 0):

Before Python 2.6, you would have used:

```
print '%s:\n\tmax: %s\n\tmin: %s' % (key,max(group),min(group))
```

to format a string using placeholders (the `%s`).

Since Python 2.6, you can use the `{}` syntax for the placeholder and `.format` instead:

```
print '{}:\n\tmax: {}\n\tmin: {}'.format(key,max(group),min(group))
```

or using positional arguments:

```
print '{0}:\n\tmax: {2}\n\tmin: {1}'.format(key,min(group),max(group))
```

(notice that I changed the order of the arguments, but the output is the same: we used `{2}` to represent the third argument...)

Just an advice: when you get a lot of arguments, it's easier to name them, as:

```
print '{key}:\n\tmax: {groupmax}\n\tmin: {groupmin}'.format(key=key,groupmin=min(group),groupmax=max(group))
```

The `.format` syntax is more powerful than the `%` one: examples are available in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Great information, but I was refering to the curly braces in the first line of code. Thanks!